# Wireless USB extension

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, printer, bluetooth

I have a printer that is not wireless, and thus need to be connected to the computer via a cable. I was wondering if something exists that's basically does what a USB cable does, but wirelessly, perhaps bluetooth?

I've looked on Google, but all I can find are those little USB nubs, but I'm pretty sure they need to be plugged into the PC, not the printer.

Comment: You should ask on hardware recommendations site.

Answer (score 1):

There is such as thing as a [WiFi USB printserver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003CFAU0U). It connects to the printer via USB, and to the network via WiFi. These things work well with intelligent printers that support a Page Description Language like PostScript or PCL5/6.

However, most USB-only printers are low-cost host-based printers. They are printers without intelligence, and which rely on Windows' graphics engine to convert the page into dots on the paper. These printers are notoriously hard to network via a printserver. You must ensure that your printer is supported by the device. Most printservers come with a printer-support-list. If your model is not in the list, you must assume that it will not work.

So the important question is: what model is your printer.